# How to add non-array value using glVertexAttribPointer()

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I know there are `uniforms` which can solve this problem but I wonder is it possible to add value like `int` using `glVertexAttribPointer()`?

Shader:

```
#version 330 core  
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in int aSize;

out vec3 vColor;

void main()  
{  
    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1.0f);
    gl_PointSize = aSize;
    vColor = aColor;
}
```

The code:

```
makeCurrent();

glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, points.vbo.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), &points.vbo.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);  //look below to the struct
glVertexAttribPointer(0, points.vertexAmount, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, points.stride * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid *)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, points.colorAmount, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, points.stride * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid *)(points.vertexAmount * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(/* ??? how to add simple int here ??? */);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

doneCurrent();
```

`points` struct:

```
struct RenderedObjects
{
    std::vector<float> vbo;
    int vertexAmount = 3;
    int colorAmount = 3;
    int stride = vertexAmount + colorAmount;
    int size = 1;
} points;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glVertexAttribPointer` is for arrays of data only. When you issue a dasw call, the GPU will fetch the `i`-th element of each attribute array which is enabled, and it uses the vertex attrib pointer data to find that element in the VBOs.

For attribute inputs for which no attribute array is enabled, you can set the value as part of the GL state. The function family [`glVertexAttib...()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttrib.xhtml) allows you to set the values for a generic vertex attribute.

OpenGL's naming conventions can get a bit confusing here. By default, vertex attributes are always treated as floating-point, even if you specify the input as integers (same with `glVertexAttribPointer()`s type parameter). So even if you might think `glVertexAttrib1i()` might set the value of an scalar integer attribute, it in reality deals with setting a `float` attribute, just by providing an integer value.

Integer attributes where added later to the GL, and you have to use `glVertexAttribI()` / `glVertexAttribIPointer()` (note the capital **I** letter) for these.

So the correct way to specify a single constant input for `layout (location = 2) in int aSize;` is:

```
 glVertexAttribI1i(2, yourIntegerValue); 
 glDisableVertexAttribArray(2); // do NOT use an array for this attribute
```

(When you create a VAO, all attribute arrays are disabled initially, so you might not need to explicitly call the `glDisableVertexAttribArray(2)` here.)

Comment: error: ‘glVertexAttribI1i’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘glVertexAttribP1ui’? Do I need some specific GL version or header? I set my shaders and context to 3.3 and I see glVertexAttribI1i is available even for 2.0.

Comment: I see obviously it is not a part of QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core

Comment: `glVertexAttribI1i` was introduced with OpenGL 3.0 and is part of the core profile, I have no idea what Qt does if this function is not part of `QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core`, butthe official  OpenGL 3.3 core specification includes this function.

Comment: I also figured out any size operations with shaders on points are available only after glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);

Comment: "I also figured out any size operations with shaders on points are available only after `glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);`", well that is correct. On desktop GL, there is this setting, GLES on the other hand does not have this state, and always behaves as if programmable point size is enabled.